# htaccess redirect http to https and keep the path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect http:// www.mysite.de/en/test/something.php?id=12 to

https:// www.mysite.de/en/test/something.php?id=12 but it always goes to

https:\ www.mysite.de/index.php....

I already tryed alot snippets and read some forums but nothing seems to work like I want it to :/
The last snippet that should do it was:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https:\\%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

but still /index.php, but this time with ?id=12 ^^

I hope you guys lend me a hand :)

And thank you for your future help guys

Comment: You have a typo on line 3. You should use forward slash "//". `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]` . The configuration seems right.

Comment: Changed it still won't work, but I found the solution. I had installed the extension real url and somehow both real url and htaccess tryed to redirect :/